# ANDROID: Broadcast Receiver continuosly receives the same message

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I made an application in android that creates TAR files by a List of files.

In the MainActivity I send a List of file to a Service: TarCreatorService.
TarCreatorService creates the TAR file and notifies MainActivity by interna broadcast.
This notification is received tons of times, I don't know why.

I have breakpoints where all the Intents are sent, and they get triggered only once, however the message from TarCreatorService and MainActivity is continuosly received by the MainActivity's BroadcastReceiver.

Here is the code:

MainActivity: send Intent to TarCreatorService

```
private void Tar(List<File> files,String EID)
    {
        Intent i=new Intent(this,TarCreatorService.class);
        i.setAction(TarCreatorService.ACTION_TAR_FILE_LIST);
        i.putExtra(TarCreatorService.EXTRA_SOURCE, (Serializable)Utils.getDtnBoxStorageDir());
        i.putExtra(TarCreatorService.EXTRA_SOURCE_FILES, (Serializable)files);
        i.putExtra(TarCreatorService.EXTRA_DESTINATION, (Serializable)this.getFilesDir());
        i.putExtra(FileHandleService.EXTRA_LOCAL_BROADCAST_DESYNC_FILES_EID, EID);
        startService(i);
    }
```

TarCreatorService: receive Intent from MainActivity and send Intent TO MainActivity

```
    public TarCreatorService() {super(TAG);}


@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {


    if(ACTION_TAR_FILE_LIST.equals(intent.getAction()))
    {
        String EID = intent.getStringExtra(FileHandleService.EXTRA_LOCAL_BROADCAST_DESYNC_FILES_EID);

        List<File> sourceFiles = (List<File>)intent.getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_SOURCE_FILES);
        File source = (File)intent.getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_SOURCE);
        File destination = (File)intent.getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_DESTINATION);
        File tar= null;
        Intent i =new Intent(ACTION_LOCAL_BROADCAST_TARCREATORSERVICE);
        try{
            tar=TAR.PackFiles(sourceFiles,source, destination);
            i.putExtra(EXTRA_LOCAL_BROADCAST_WHAT, LOCAL_BROADCAST_TAR);
            i.putExtra(EXTRA_LOCAL_BROADCAST_TAR, (Serializable)tar);
            i.putExtra(FileHandleService.EXTRA_LOCAL_BROADCAST_DESYNC_FILES_EID,EID);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(i);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            i.putExtra(FileHandleService.EXTRA_LOCAL_BROADCAST_DESYNC_FILES_EID,EID);
            i.putExtra(EXTRA_LOCAL_BROADCAST_WHAT, LOCAL_BROADCAST_TAR_ERROR);
            i.putExtra(EXTRA_LOCAL_BROADCAST_TAR_ERROR, (Serializable)e);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(i);
        };
    }

}
```

MainActivity: Receiving intent from TarCreatorService through internal BroadcastReceiver

```
private BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver= new BroadcastReceiver() {

...

else if(TarCreatorService.ACTION_LOCAL_BROADCAST_TARCREATORSERVICE.equals(intent.getAction()) && intent.hasExtra(TarCreatorService.EXTRA_LOCAL_BROADCAST_WHAT))
                switch(intent.getIntExtra(TarCreatorService.EXTRA_LOCAL_BROADCAST_WHAT, -1))
                {
                    case TarCreatorService.LOCAL_BROADCAST_TAR :
                        String EID= intent.getStringExtra(FileHandleService.EXTRA_LOCAL_BROADCAST_DESYNC_FILES_EID);
                        File tar= (File)intent.getSerializableExtra(TarCreatorService.EXTRA_LOCAL_BROADCAST_TAR);
                        SpawnMessage(tar.getAbsolutePath());




                        break;
                    case TarCreatorService.LOCAL_BROADCAST_TAR_ERROR :
                        Exception e=(Exception)intent.getSerializableExtra(TarCreatorService.EXTRA_LOCAL_BROADCAST_TAR_ERROR);
                        SpawnMessage(e.toString());
                        break;
                }
}
```

The latter piece of code gets infinitely triggered.

I also register the BroadcastReceiver in onResume() and unregister in onDestroy()

I REALLY can't figure out hot to fix this

Comment: UP: while testing this application I noticed that I get this bug only the SECOND TIME I try to make a TAR file...

Comment: UP AGAIN: more testing and debugging led me to understand that the problem is the LocalBroadcastManager:
The first time I send an Intent from a Service to the MainActivity, the Intent is received once.
The second time is received twice 
The third time is received three times and so on...

So... I'm still confused but I hope this could help you to... help me :)

Comment: have you found the solution to this problem? I believe I have the same issue